# Transition child width 100% when parent width changes

Tags: html, css

I am having issues coming up with a way to make a child have transitionable width while making the parent change instantaneously.

Using the following example:

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 1s;
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
}

.parent:hover {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

When `.parent` is hovered, its width should increase, and then the child should take 1s to catch up to the parents width.

Is there any way to achieve this? I don't want the parent to transition as it will cause a lot of jumping around as the parent grows instead of moving everything at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `transition`, since the child's `width` **value** doesn't actually change - it was `100%` before and `100%` after.

In this case you can use an animation that will start from `50%` if the new `width`, and proceed to the `100%`. If the hover ends, the child `width` will go back to the parent's width immediately.

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
}

.parent:hover {
  width: 50%;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  animation: 1s both grow;
}

@keyframes grow {
  from { width: 50%; }
  to { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So keep in mind that `div` elements are `block` elements. They will fill the full-width of their parent unless you style them otherwise.

This makes using percentages problematic without adding a `keyframes` animation. Though there is nothing wrong with defining an animation.

But if you give exact widths with other types of css units, you can achieve the affect by also changing the width of the child when the parent is hovered.

Below I changed the parent width to `25vw` and assigned the same width to the child. Then, when the parent is hovered, change the child width to `100%` will cause it to transition.

In the original case, you were only changing the parents `width`, and the child's width never transitioned because in both states of the parent, its value was `100%`.

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 25vw;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  width: 25vw;
  transition: width 1s linear;
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
}

.parent:hover {
  width: 50%;
}
.parent:hover > .child {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that **you're child's width is technically not changing**. It remains **100% of the parent's width**, so though it's physical size as constrained within the parent changes, it's **relative width value is still 100%**, so no transition is being applied to it.

Using `vw` units will allow you to create a fluid layout with the width values being **relative to the viewport** (window) width instead of the containing div.

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 25vw;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  width: 25vw;
  transition: width 1s;
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
}

.parent:hover, .parent:hover .child {
  width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```